# Why is the Time Zone offset of Apps Script Session.getScriptTimeZone() one hour different than in the project properties?

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone-offset

In Apps Script, the project file has it's own time zone setting:

[image: Project Properties time zone]

In this case the time zone offset is minus 5.  But when my code logs the script time zone, it's minus 4!  It's off by one hour.  How can I fix my code to get the correct time zone offset?

Here is the code:

```
function getTimezoneOffset(){
  var testMonth = "March",
      testDayOfMnth = "26",
      testYr = "2016";

  var hour = "10:00";

  Logger.log("Script Time Zone: " + Session.getScriptTimeZone());

  var dateString = testMonth + " " + testDayOfMnth + ", " + testYr;
  Logger.log("dateString: " + dateString);

  var date = new Date(dateString);

  var scrptTimeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  Logger.log("Session.getScriptTimeZone(): " + Session.getScriptTimeZone());

  var scriptTimeZone = Utilities.formatDate(date, scrptTimeZone, 'Z');
  Logger.log("scriptTimeZone: " + scriptTimeZone);
};
```

### Log print out

[image: Log of print out]

Comment: Could it be due to [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (Daylight Saving Time)?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue.  Daylight Savings Time starts on Sunday March 13th.  The day I ran the script was Feb 28th, but the date being used for the new date object is March 26th.  So, Apps Script automatically adjusted the future time for Daylight Savings even when the date that the script runs isn't Daylight Savings Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is due to DST (on March 13th).
Try this:

```
var date1 = new Date("March 12, 2016 10:00");  // EST – Eastern Standard Time
Logger.log("dateString: " + date1);
// result: dateString: Sat Mar 12 2016 10:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)


var date2 = new Date("March 13, 2016 10:00");  // EDT – Eastern Daylight Time
Logger.log("dateString: " + date2);
// result: dateString: Sun Mar 13 2016 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```